I am getting below error while evaluating the AEM project expression in VS code IDE
I am getting this error while evaluating the expression in VS code IDE : Cannot evaluate because of java.lang.IllegalStateException: Project abc cannot be found..
my launch.json is as below;
{ "version": "0.2.0", "configurations": [
{ "type": "java", "name": "Debug-AEM 4502", "projectName": "abc", "request": "attach", "hostName": "localhost", "port": 5005, "timeout": 30000 } ] }
I have tried modifying fields in launch.json

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
